# how slow may the nested iteration be in php?

Tags: php, loops, iteration

In my nested **empty iteration**, $arr1 has 90000 items, when $arr2 has 9000 items,  **the whole nested iteration used less then 3 minutes,**

but when $arr2 just add 1000 to 10000 items, **the time fly to more then 100 minutes,** so curious, have it to do with cpu,memory, IO or php itself?

```
$arr1 = array(...);
$arr2 = array(...);

$starttime = time();

foreach($arr1 as $v1){
    foreach($arrs as $v2){
    }
}

$endtime = time() - $starttime;
```

Comment: your question is too broad there ary two many variable to figure out "how slow it may be " this might beg a better quesitons for programmers stack

Comment: I can't reproduce your results

Comment: Unless those 1000 elements change some swapping or caching behavior this can't be right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to read some book of [algorithmic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms). (check this topic at google books)

The problem of 100 minutes is your algorithm design, not php, cpu ,etc (this also matters of course).

Seems yours is O(n^2) , but without code inside the for loops, I cant said if it is worse than that.

Hope it helps